# Recovering data from iMac internal hard drive when you can't login to your account anymore

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, imac

I'm looking for help on recovering data from an internal hard drive on my iMac.

I have a iMac that I purchased online in 2018 refurbished. It had been slowing down over the last few months, but I chalked it up to software bloat. One day, the system froze, so I held the power button down to force it to power down. It booted up to the login screen fine. I entered my password, and it started the loading bar. However, the loading bar got to 100% and the desktop never showed up (after 30 minutes or so of being stuck at 100%).

I booted into the recovery OS by holding down Alt-Command-R. When I opened up the disk utility, it froze. I then opened up the terminal and wrote `diskutil list` Expecting something like the first screenshot from [this guy's blog](https://medium.com/macoclock/get-around-your-mac-disks-892db0a671af). The text dumps out fine until it hits the "synthesized" entry, and then the diskutil list command hangs forever (I tried killing the process in another terminal, and couldn't).

By displaying the properties of the "working" disks (i.e., the disks that I can list without hanging the system) I can see that the SMART status of those disks list as VERIFIED. However, there appears to be a "synthesized" disk that causes the computer to hang whenever it tries to read it.

I've tried resetting the nvram with the `nvram -c` command, and I've tried resetting the SMC by unplugging the computer's power supply for a few seconds then plugging it back in.

I tried booting up a Ubuntu Live USB stick and mounting the filesystem there:

```
# ./apfs-fuse -o allow_other /dev/sda2/ ~/mountpoint
Need to specify two devices for a fusion drive.
Unable to load container.
```

This used to be managed by my university's IT department. I tried reaching out to them to see if there was any encryption or other tools that affect this. I haven't heard back from them. I no longer am at that university.

At this point, I'm beginning to wonder if it's possible to access the data on that hard drive anymore. I don't know enough about how hard drives are formatted to know what to do next, so I come to the elders of StackExchange seeking deep wisdom.

---

### Edit 2023-09-15

Thanks to those who have commented thus far.

This is what I have [Refurbished 2015 iMac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N4HJ8MU). I think that I have Mojave or Catalina installed on it, but I'm not 100% sure. I was keeping it on an old operating system to be compatible with some older versions of software for work.

Here is a screenshot of the output of diskutil. The command freezes while outputting the entries for the synthesized disk. It does not freeze if I look at the internal physical disks.

[image: Screenshot of diskutil list]

Comment: What OS is on the Mac? Do you know precisely what model it is, as there is no 2018. Can you get a shot of what `diskutil list` does manage to find [even if it has to be a photo]. The synthesised disk is the one it will actually be booting from - but what it's made of is equally important.

Comment: This sounds more like a physical failure of the drive hardware than some kind of software issue. BTW, "SMART status: Verified" is mostly meaningless. Drives almost never admit they're failing. Look at the counters for failing/spared/pending sectors. If any of them are nonzero, then you probably have a failing drive. If so, consider using GNU ddrescue (with a log file) to try to image what's left of the drive. Dying drives take forever re-reading each bad sector before giving up, so expect the recovery process to run for literally days.

Comment: @Spiff - if it's a Fusion drive… or a split Fusion drive, we need to establish whether it can be rebuilt before going onto data recovery - a split Fusion is pretty much 'not recoverable', unless you can re-fuse it.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have updated my question to include additional information.

Comment: I'm by no means the expert on this, but there are a lot of QAs on Ask Different about various states of failure for Fusion drives. One thing I have garnered is that you can't rebuild a Fusion without destroying the data on it - yet if it's split you have a much smaller chance of getting data off it with recovery tools - a fusion is a bit like a RAID0, half the data is on one drive, half on the other. Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=rebuild+fusion & especially pay attention to anything by Klanomath or David Anderson [& not me] They're the resident experts in this field.